# Python file preprocessing (convert column from discrete ranges of values to contiguous range of values.)

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting

I have a dataset of the form:

```
user_id::item_id1::rating::timestamp
user_id::item_id2::rating::timestamp
user_id::item_id3::rating::timestamp
user_id::item_id4::rating::timestamp
```

I require the item_ids (there are n distinct item ids in sorted order. Subsequent rows could have the same item ids or different but its guaranteed to be sorted) to be contiguous from 1 to n and they are currently ranging from 1 to k

for k >> n

I have the following code but it isn't quite correct and have been at it for a couple of hours so would really appreciate any help regarding this or if there is a simpler way to do this in python I would really appreciate guidance regarding that as well.

I currently have the following code:

```
def reOrderItemIds(inputFile,outputFile):
        #This is a list in the range of 1 to 10681.
        itemIdsRange = set(range(1,10682))
        #currKey = 1
        currKey = itemIdsRange.pop()
        lastContiguousKey=1
        #currKey+1
        contiguousKey=itemIdsRange.pop()
        f = open(inputFile)
        g = open(outputFile,"w")
        oldKeyToNewKeyMap = dict()
        for line in f:
                if int(line.split(":")[1]) == currKey and int(line.split(":")[1])==lastContiguousKey:
                        g.write(line)
                elif int(line.split(":")[1])!=currKey and int(line.split(":")[1])!=contiguousKey:
                        oldKeyToNewKeyMap[line.split(":")[1]]=contiguousKey
                        lastContiguousKey=contiguousKey
                        #update current key to the value of the current key.
                        currKey=int(line.split(":")[1])
                        contiguousKey=itemIdsRange.pop()
                        g.write(line.split(":")[0]+":"+str(lastContiguousKey)+":"+line.split(":")[2]+":"+line.split(":")[3])
                elif int(line.split(":")[1])==currKey and int(line.split(":")[1])!=contiguousKey:
                        g.write(line.split(":")[0]+":"+str(lastContiguousKey)+":"+line.split(":")[2]+":"+line.split(":")[3])

                elif int(line.split(":")[1])!=currKey and int(line.split(":")[1])==contiguousKey:
                        currKey = int(line.split(":")[1])
                        lastContiguousKey=contiguousKey
                        oldKeyToNewKeyMap[line.split(":")[1]] = lastContiguousKey
                        contiguousKey=itemIdsRange.pop()
                        g.write(line.split(":")[0]+":"+str(lastContiguousKey)+":"+line.split(":")[2]+":"+line.split(":")[3])
        f.close()
        g.close()
```

Example:

```
1::1::3::100
10::1::5::104
20::2::3::110
1::5::2::104
```

I require the output to be of the form:

```
1::1::3::100
10::1::5::104
20::2::3::110
1::3::2::104
```

so only the item_ids column changes and everything else remains the same.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Is your example an example of your functions output or an Example of the dataset?

Comment: Is there a typo in the third line of your expected output? Should it be ```20::2::3::110```?

Answer (score 1):

Because your data is already sorted by item_id - you can use `itertools.groupby()` which makes easy work of the solution.

```
from operator import itemgetter
from itertools import groupby

item_id = itemgetter(1)
def reOrderItemIds(inputFile,outputFile):
    n = 1
    with open(inputFile)as infile, open(outputFile,"w") as outfile:
        dataset = (line.split('::') for line in infile)
        for key, group in groupby(dataset, item_id):
            for line in group:
                line[1] = str(n)
                outfile.write('::'.join(line))
            n += 1
```

Comment: I think this will change the ids to be sequential but won't leave alone the ones with repeated ids. Notice the second column in the expected output is "1, 1, 2, 3".

Comment: ```won't leave alone the ones with repeated ids``` - hmmm I don't understand that, did you try it?  OP specified *only the item_ids column changes and everything else remains the same*.  My output matches OP's expected output.  ```groupby()``` is grouping by the second item in the lists/lines.

Comment: Ah my apologies. I see now you are iterating over each `line in group`.

Comment: I'm still trying to refine it - I'd like to reduce the number of writes to ```outfile``` by aggregating the modified lines.  It could be done with a ```list``` but I'm trying to figure out how to make a generator....

Comment: Couldn't you turn your whole function into a generator basically by replacing `outfile.write` with `yield`?

Comment: Yes.  Then I looked at the read side and was wondering why I didn't limit the disk access there also.

Answer (score 0):

With my apologies for grossly misreading your question the first time, suppose `data` is a file containing

```
1::1::3::100
10::1::5::104
20::2::3::110
30::5::3::121
40::9::7::118
50::10::2::104
```

(If your data cannot all be cast to integers, this could be modified.)

```
>>> with open('data', 'r') as datafile:
...   dataset = datafile.read().splitlines()
...
>>> ids = {0}
>>> for i, line in enumerate(dataset):
...   data = list(map(int, line.split('::')))
...   if data[1] not in ids:
...     data[1] = max(ids) + 1
...     ids.add(data[1])
...   dataset[i] = '::'.join((str(d) for d in data))
...
>>> print('\n'.join(dataset))
1::1::3::100
10::1::5::104
20::2::3::110
30::3::3::121
40::4::7::118
50::5::2::104
```

Again, if your dataset is large, faster solutions can be devised.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but I think all this achieves is sorting the files by item_id, in my case the lines are already sorted by item id, I need the discrete values to be made contiguous as in the case of the example I indicated above.

Comment: Apologies for misreading your problem statement. I have reinstated my answer with applicable code (assuming I now understand correctly).